# How can i do to show up the text when i want to alter table from my mysql workbench app?

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench, alter-table, appearance

I'm using mysql workbench version 8.0.36.(latest version)
The problem is when i click alter table from my mysql workbench it show up but the words can't see but it can click and work. Only can't see what words are writing.
It is look like this.
[The problem is like this. Words are disappear only in alter table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGCbH.jpg)

It is totally fine in other tab.
[Totally fine in running query side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3rYB.jpg)

[The word should appear in the box.But it didn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz88o.jpg)

It should be appeared like this.
[It should appear like this normally.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyLok.png)
[It should show up like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7UqC.png)

I try to change white theme from dark theme. But it also didn't work.
[Change it to white theme but it didn't solve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RloCm.png)

I also try to change the appearance setting. But the application show up error and close automatically and it also didn't work.
[Appearance setting of mysql workbench.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfC3m.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on version **8.0.36** on mac os **sonoma**.
When creating or editing a table, the UI is missing some buttons, and the table name input is not showing the text.

I opened a bug on MySQL, and in the meantime I downgraded to version **8.0.34** and it fixed the proble.

You can find previous versions here: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Comment: I'm previously using version 8.034. Yes, you correct. With old version the UI error is solved. But it can't create EER model with that old version. That's why i upgrade it to 8.036.

I tested again with 8.034 version but the same error occur (cant' create EER model).